# running python script with an ECS task

Tags: python, amazon-ecs

I have an ECS task setup which, when with a Command override **ls**, produces expected results with my CloudWatch log stream: **test.py**.  my script **test.py** takes one parameter.  I am wondering how I can execute this script with python3 (which exists in my container) using the command override.  Essentially, I want to execute the command:

```
 python3 test.py hello
```

how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I did something similar:

In your docker build file, make the command you want to run as the last instruction. In your case:

```
CMD python3 test.py hello
```

To make it more extensible, use environment variables. For instance, do something like:

```
CMD ["python3", "test.py"]
```

But make the parameter come from an environment variable you pass into the container definition in your task.